# Positive Integer in Velocity Template

Tags: apache, velocity

I need to append $ symbol with price values. From db i am getting values like: "125.00", "--", "blah blah".

I need to append $ symbol only for valid integers. How can i do this,i have tried below code:

```
#if($!{myDao.getMyBal($myId)} % 2 == 0)
    $$!{myDao.getMyBal($myId)}
#else
    $!{myDao.getMyBal($myId)}
#end
```

Comment: Tried parseInt, but throwing errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make "$" symbol a variable first. then need to append it.

```
#set($symbol="$")
#if($!{myDao.getMyBal($myId)} % 2 == 0)
    $symbol $!{myDao.getMyBal($myId)}
```

Comment: Updated like below, always its moving to else condition.  I think i getting getMyBal($myId) value as String and numerical operations are getting failed. 

`code`
#set($symbol="$")
#if($!{myDao.getMyBal($myId)} % 2 == 0)
    $symbol $!{myDao.getMyBal($myId)}
#else
    $!{myDao.getMyBal($myId)}
#end
`code`

Comment: yeah probably then you must try parseInt() if you are getting $myId in string.

Comment: Wrote a Java method for validate integers and Fixed this issue